# react context vs redux vs hooks, which one should consider and how each one is different

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

React has released the Context API and React Hooks but most of us are familiar with Redux, which one we should consider.

What is the purpose of using React Hooks and the React Context API? Please explain in detail how React Redux, Hooks and the Context API are different from each other.

Comment: Context API, hooks, and redux all serve very different purposes. None are substitutes for the others.

Comment: what are different purpose of each one

Comment: Its only a matter of composition and how you want to structure your code. What to choose where, depends on what problem you are trying to solve. Both redux and the context api with hooks works just fine and can solve the same problems. The big difference is scoping. Redux relies on global-state, while context gives you a more defined scope making it easier to "decouple" parts of your application.

Comment: Redux: An external library for managing state. Hooks: [A way to reuse logic in components](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) which can include component state management. Context: [A way to pass values to child components without using props](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) which can also be used to hold, or provide access to, state.

Comment: Kent Dodds has an excellent blog post detailing exactly this: [Application State Management with React](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/application-state-management-with-react)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**React Context** is used to store state and share it across multiple components. It is especially useful when you have a deep tree of components and do not want to pass down state as props across multiple levels of components. Contexts in React consist of a Provider (where you set the value of the context) and a Consumer (where you get the value).

**React Hooks** provide a `useContext` Hook, which is another way to access context values. `useContext` replaces the Consumer component.

**Redux** is a state management library. It does a lot more than simply storing state with a set/get interface as Contexts do. Internally, Redux actually uses React Context to store its state. However, it additionally forces you to change state via actions. This makes sense if your state changes are complex (e.g. a single action should change multiple parts of your state). In a complex application, Redux can prevent bugs and inconsistent state.

As a rule of thumb, you should use React Context as long as your state changes are simple. If you run into problems where it is hard to keep multiple parts of your state in sync, it might make sense to consider Redux.

Whether you want to use Context Consumers or Hooks is totally up to you and a matter of taste. The advantage of using Hooks is that you can consume multiple contexts more easily without having a deep component tree.

Context Consumers:

```
   <AuthenticationContext.Consumer>
       {user => (
           <LanguageContext.Consumer>
               {language => (
                   <StatusContext.Consumer>
                       {status => (
                           ...
                       )}
                   </StatusContext.Consumer>
               )}
           </LanguageContext.Consumer>
       )}
    </AuthenticationContext.Consumer>
```

`useContext` Hooks:

```js
const user = useContext(AuthenticationContext)
const language = useContext(LanguageContext)
const status = useContext(StatusContext)
```

As for the Providers, they are the same whether you use Hooks or not.

Comment: Seems like Redux is like class in React would.